# Any idea what is going on with the power button here? When the computer is on, sometimes the button restarts it. Sometimes it keeps it off

Tags: motherboard, power

ny idea what is going on with the power button here?

I have made these two videos.. no need to watch them all start to finish..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcC84J5jCa0 (weirdpower) 5min
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ay-ljw0hMpM (weirdpower2) 1min30sec

And everything in the second video is probably in the first one too.

In the first video..

Straight way 15 seconds into the first video, you see something funny's going on. I push the power button and it resets

And at 25 seconds in. While it's on. I tap the power button. while it's on. And it turns off immediately.

At 44sec I hold the power button and it stays off

At 53sec I push the power button and it turns off immediately after turning on

At 1:18 I hold the power button and when I release the power button it turns back on

I really don't understand what's going on.

If it were connected to the reset pins then I guess it wouldn't turn on at all?

I'm used to where if you long press the power button then it goes off. But here long press seems to reset it. But i've also found that a really long long press holding it for 10 second after the power is off, and stays off

The long press at 1:25 turned it off and it didn't turn back on when I released it immediately after it turned off. But other times when i've released it after it turned off, it turned back on.

I'm really confused by it.

It's not a big problem.. As, if I want to turn it on I push power. And if I want to turn it off I shutdown windows, or pull out the power cord.

I'm wondering if anybody has any idea what on earth is going on.

The computer is HP Pavilion a6001.uk. The motherboard looks rather like this https://support.hp.com/nz-en/document/c00910113

The power button is connected to a connector that plugs onto a chunk of pins. So it's not like the power connector has a 2 pin connector on it. I could potentially try turning the connector the other way around but i'm wary of doing that 'cos i'm not sure if it'd damage anything? I can't see what each of the pins do. No doubt that chunk includes power pins and reset pins but i'm not sure re any others. And what if I turn it around..

I'm really not sure what could cause the issue I see?

Comment: Is that a HP machine?  My HP case looks very similar and the power button is flaky.  Probably worn out.

Comment: Check the power button hardware as suggested. Also update BIOS (UEFI) and power drivers.

Answer (score 0):

For replacing the power button, see instructions in the HP article
[Replacing the Power Supply in HP Pavilion 500 Desktop PCs](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04100691).

The computer model is not exactly the same as yours,
so you will need to adapt the procedure.

If you prefer to avoid this, at least temporarily, you may also
set the BIOS to boot automatically when connected to AC power.
You could then turn on the laptop with the wall socket.

Comment: You write "If you prefer to avoid this, at least temporarily, you may also set the BIOS to boot automatically when connected to AC power. You could then turn on the laptop with the wall socket." <-- it turns on it's an issue turning it off from the power button

Comment: Your instructions are for a laptop though this is a desktop.  I could perhaps look into sourcing a replacement button and cable

Comment: Sorry about the mixup of models, but your computer model is pretty hard to find. [This article](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04100691) might be to a more similar model. If you can't turn it off without the power button, you have more problems than just the power button.

Comment: You write "If you can't turn it off without the power button" <-- no idea what you are talking about there, that could be read various ways. And I didn't say any such thing. Obviously I can turn a computer off without a power button, as can you. Maybe you were thinking if windows shutdown option doesn't turn it off, well, it does(And that has nothing to do with the power button. So, as I said  in my question, any idea what is going on with{including related to btw} the power button".

Comment: Very simple idea: Bad switch goes out, new switch goes in, problem solved. It had better be solved, or you have a much more costly hardware problem.